# How do you partition disk that the system is running on? (Linux)

Tags: partitioning, elementaryos

I want to know how to partition the disk that the system is running on(Linux), and not with external media from the system it's self. Also, I need it with a Gui too(I can't partition with the terminal). (And just to make this clear, the disk that the OS is running on) Thank you

Comment: Plus I just don't want to switch to OpenSUSE for YaST's partitioning tool I want this on Elementary OS Hera.

Comment: And I know what Libparted or Gparted or Gdisks or kde partition and a couple more

Answer (score 0):

You can partition areas of the disk that are outside of the partition & filesystem the
OS is running from. You cannot modify a mounted partition, which the OS necessarily resides on. GParted is a well-known and reliable GUI partitioning tool.

Comment: Boot from a "live disk" (at least for Ubuntu that is the SAME boot media you use to install from, but run in "Try mode") and use your partitioning tool from there. Then your system disks are free to modify - in a sane manner; it is easy to destroy it too.